# ASP .NET Core: Get User IP Address

Tags: database, asp.net-core, get, ip, ip-address

I have a table : with a model

```
public class ArticleLike:BaseEntity
{
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserIp { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

How can I  get Ipaddress of user ?
I had to write method of it on service or repository?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get client user IP address

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Client IP address can be retrieved via HttpContext.Connection object.

Property RemoteIpAddress is the client IP address. The returned object (System.Net.IpAddress) can be used to check whether it is IPV4 or IPV6 address.

For example, if you get a result like ::1, this is the IPv6 format

Answer (score 6):

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

or

```
var remoteIpAddress = httpContext.GetFeature<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress;
```

**Simple Usage :**

In Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
    return Content(ip);
}
```

}

And in Startup File :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: I use from this method but I get IP like this :fe80::18a3:6c10:468f:f212%16
I cannot use from your code because I Have error: 'type' does not contain a definition for 'identifier'
on the HttpContext

Comment: I finally can get IP address and add it to data base . But now I want to show on View when click on heart then change  its color and add its number of like. I am really weak in writing if condition code on View. :(